# Linux server memory usage and cache availability

Tags: memory-usage

It's a topic already discussed, but there's a point that i'm not really sure about.

I want to see whether my server memory is well dimensioned (os is centos 6). I run the processus that will be running on the server as production, and check the memory usage.

Checking how many free memory it remains, I have understood reading many posts that cached memory is counted as used by tools like top or free, whereas it is available memory for processus if needed. (I find free -m output clearer since it displays the buffer/cache line)

Is it always true ? Because I read too some posts saying that interpreting the cached memory as available memory is not always true, for example when the system uses initramfs (instead of initrd, if I well understood ?). I tried to dig a little reading about initramfs and initrd, but I have to admit it gave me some headaches :/

So now i'm little confused :
 - how can I get the "real" amount of memory remaining free : should I check whether my system rely on initramfs instead of initrd to see if what is displayed as cached memory can be counted as free ?
 - is it possible for a processus to use memory differently, so that its consumption (while processus running) appears only on cached memory display, and not on used memory display ?

Thanks a lot,
and sorry if it's not very clear, it's not neither in my mind

Comment: Just to know, where should I have asked this question ? I guess stackoverflow isn't a correct place neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most purposes it's perfectly okay to view cashed memory as free memory. But in the case of RAMdisk filesystems such as initramfs, A small portion of your memory will be dedicated to the RAMdisk. That portion of memory is not considered free, but in most cases this RAMdisk is small enough to be relatively insignificant on memory consumption. If for some reason you need to know exactly how much free memory you have at all times you would either need to identify the exact size of the RAMdisk or choose not to use a RAMdisk system.

Comment: I see... Do you know what is the average size of that portion, I mean very globally, like about 10go, or more 1go, or 100mo ?

Comment: I think cache memory is used for performance, quick access to memory often used... But if it's considered as free memory, I could consider too that this memory is useless, and I could reduce the amount of my server memory only to used amount (and a little more for secure) ?

Comment: Cached memory is used for a performance boost. Heavily used items on the hard disk are loaded into memory for quick access. It's not necessary to have, but it is much faster. In the event that the system processes need more memory, cached memory will be automatically reduced. That's why it can be considered free.

Comment: So I think, when dimensionning your memory on a server : make your server work as it will be working the more in prod, then check the max used memory & max used cached memory, and additionning both give you the most optimal amount of memory you should have ... Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to prioritize cached memory. It's size will always change and the more memory you have, the bigger your cache size will be. I would just worry about how much ram your services need and add a little extra for things like caching.